Why is my solve_ivp stuck in an infinite loop?
I'm trying to solve a problem involving a fixed-bed reactor that uses a system of ordinary differential equations, but for some reason it gets stuck in an infinite loop. Here's the code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

" Dependant variables : Fet, Fac, Fo, Fp, Fa, Fc, Ft, Pet, Pac, Po, Pp, Pa, Pc, P"

def f(W, y):
    
    Fet, Fac, Fo, Fp, Fa, Fc, Ft, Pet, Pac, Po, Pp, Pa, Pc, P = y 

    r1 = 0.1036*np.exp(-3674/T)*((Po*Pet*Pac*(1+1.7*Pa)))/((1+0.583*Po*(1+1.7*Pa))*(1+6.8*Pac))
    r2 = 1.9365*(10**5)*np.exp(-10116/T)*(Po*(1+0.68*Pa))/(1+0.76*Po*(1+0.68*Pa))

    m = Fet * 28.06 + Fac * 60.052 + Fo * 32 + Fp * 86.09 + Fa * 18.02 + Fc * 44.01  # [ lb / min ]
    G = m / A_c                                                                      # [ lb / (min * ft ^2) ]
    beta = (1.75 * G**2 / (rho_0 * g_c * D_p)) * ((1-phi) / phi**3)

    dFet_dW = -r1 - r2
    dFac_dW = -r1
    dFo_dW  = -r1/2 - 3*r2
    dFp_dW  = r1
    dFa_dW  = r1 + 2*r2
    dFc_dW  = 2*r2
    dFt_dW  = -r1/2
    
    dP_dW   = -(beta/(A_c*(1-phi)*rho_c))*(P_0/P)*(Ft/Ft_0)
    dPet_dW = (Ft*P*dFet_dW-Fet*P*dFt_dW+Fet*Ft*dP_dW)/Ft**2
    dPac_dW = (Ft*P*dFac_dW-Fac*P*dFt_dW+Fac*Ft*dP_dW)/Ft**2
    dPo_dW  = (Ft*P*dFo_dW -Fo*P*dFt_dW +Fo*Ft*dP_dW)/Ft**2
    dPp_dW  = (Fp*P*dFp_dW -Fp*P*dFt_dW +Fp*Ft*dP_dW)/Ft**2
    dPa_dW  = (Fa*P*dFa_dW -Fa*P*dFt_dW +Fa*Ft*dP_dW)/Ft**2
    dPc_dW  = (Fc*P*dFc_dW -Fc*P*dFc_dW +Fc*Ft*dP_dW)/Ft**2
    
    return np.array([dFet_dW, dFac_dW, dFo_dW, dFp_dW, dFa_dW, dFc_dW, dFt_dW, dPet_dW, dPac_dW, dPo_dW, dPp_dW, dPa_dW, dPc_dW, dP_dW])

# Integration points
W_span = np.array([0, 100])
points = np.linspace(W_span[0], W_span[1], num = 101)

# Initial conditions
P_0 = 128       # psi
T   = 423       # Kelvin

Fet_0, Fac_0, Fo_0, Fp_0, Fa_0, Fc_0 = 11, 11, 1.9, 0, 0, 0
Ft_0  = Fet_0 + Fac_0 + Fo_0

Pp_0, Pa_0, Pc_0  = 0, 0, 0
Pet_0 = (Fet_0/Ft_0)*P_0
Pac_0 = (Fac_0/Ft_0)*P_0
Po_0  = (Fo_0/Ft_0)*P_0
P_0   = Pet_0 + Pac_0 + Po_0

y_0 = np.array([Fet_0, Fac_0, Fo_0, Fp_0, Fa_0, Fc_0, Ft_0, Pet_0, Pac_0, Po_0, Pp_0, Pa_0, Pc_0, P_0])

# Constants
phi = 0.5                                                                        # Void fraction
A_c = 0.0122718463                                                               # straight section area of the catalyst  [ ft ^2 ]
rho_c = 60                                                                       # dry catalyst density                   [ lb / ft ^3 ]    
g_c = 115826.4                                                                   # gravity conversion factor              [ lb * ft / (min ^2 *lbf) ]
D_p = 0.020833333                                                                # average particle diameter              [ ft ]
M_0 = (28.05 * Fet_0 + 60.052 * Fac_0 + 31.998 * Fo_0) / (Ft_0)                  # molar mass of the initial mixture      [ lb / lbmol]
rho_0 = (128 * M_0) / (10.73 + 731.07)                                           # Initial density                        [ lb / ft  ^3 ]

# Solution IVP
sol = solve_ivp(f, W_span, y_0, t_eval=points)
W   = sol.t
Fet = sol.y[0]
Fac = sol.y[1]
Fo  = sol.y[2]
Fp  = sol.y[3]
Fa  = sol.y[4]
Fc  = sol.y[5]
Ft  = sol.y[6]
Pet = sol.y[7]
Pac = sol.y[8]
Po  = sol.y[9]
Pp  = sol.y[10]
Pa  = sol.y[11]
Pc  = sol.y[12]
P   = sol.y[13]

I tried to write some print() along the code while trying to understand what could be happening and realized that some values like Fet, Fac, Fo, Fp, Fa, Fc, Ft, m, G and beta didn't change. On the other hand, r1, r2, Pet, Pac, Po, Pp, Pa, Pc and P changed cyclically.

I don't see any loops here.  Where, exactly, does the code get stuck?

@JohnGordon. In some of my attempts to understand the problem, I wrote some print() along the function f(W, y) and then noticed this looping behavior. Cordially, Renato.

You have still not said exactly where the program gets stuck.

Why is the observed behavior wrong? Of what kind is the reference for the exact solution? Are the default tolerances appropriate for the component magnitudes?

I think it gets stuck inside the solver, because it can't converge. I'll attach the spreadsheet it receives at the end of the iteration. Sorry for not being so clear, I'm new to python and this website.                                                                     'message str 56 Required step size is less than spacing between numbers.
nfev int 1 319682
njev int 1 0
nlu  int 1 0
sol NoneType 1 None
status int 1 -1
success bool 1 False
t Array of float64 (1,) 0.000000000000000000e+00'

@LutzLehmann. I've just tried scaling down the problem and it seems to have worked. The molar flow rates Fj of the reactants are decreasing and that of the products is increasing. I searched further on the internet and found out about the implementation for 3-body motion, and there the DOP853 method is applied with rtol = 1e-10 and atol = 1e-13.

There are two issues, that the (per-component) control parameters for the step-size selection might not be appropriate, leading to strange errors. And that the system might be stiff. Which requires another solver, DOP853 is the best medium order solver for mightly stiff problems. The second situation might be completely masked by the first one.

Changing the solver method avoids the hanging:
sol = solve_ivp(f, W_span, y_0, t_eval=points, method='Radau')

Now we face a problem: Required step size is less than spacing between numbers.
Using a break point and examining the variables at W = 0.0, I noticed that dP_dW = -7465419.406392181 and other huge values such as this one. There might be something wrong with the calculation of the partial derivatives.
See Required step size is less than spacing between numbers
I scaled the time variable W to 1E-9 and plot the solutions right before failure. Use the following code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

TIME_SCALE = 1.0E9

" Dependant variables : Fet, Fac, Fo, Fp, Fa, Fc, Ft, Pet, Pac, Po, Pp, Pa, Pc, P"

def f(W, y):
    Fet, Fac, Fo, Fp, Fa, Fc, Ft, Pet, Pac, Po, Pp, Pa, Pc, P = y 

    r1 = 0.1036*np.exp(-3674/T)*((Po*Pet*Pac*(1+1.7*Pa)))/((1+0.583*Po*(1+1.7*Pa))*(1+6.8*Pac))
    r2 = 1.9365*(10**5)*np.exp(-10116/T)*(Po*(1+0.68*Pa))/(1+0.76*Po*(1+0.68*Pa))

    m = Fet * 28.06 + Fac * 60.052 + Fo * 32 + Fp * 86.09 + Fa * 18.02 + Fc * 44.01  # [ lb / min ]
    G = m / A_c                                                                      # [ lb / (min * ft ^2) ]
    beta = (1.75 * G**2 / (rho_0 * g_c * D_p)) * ((1-phi) / phi**3)

    dFet_dW = -r1 - r2
    dFac_dW = -r1
    dFo_dW  = -r1/2 - 3*r2
    dFp_dW  = r1
    dFa_dW  = r1 + 2*r2
    dFc_dW  = 2*r2
    dFt_dW  = -r1/2
    
    dP_dW   = -(beta/(A_c*(1-phi)*rho_c))*(P_0/P)*(Ft/Ft_0)
    dPet_dW = (Ft*P*dFet_dW-Fet*P*dFt_dW+Fet*Ft*dP_dW)/Ft**2
    dPac_dW = (Ft*P*dFac_dW-Fac*P*dFt_dW+Fac*Ft*dP_dW)/Ft**2
    dPo_dW  = (Ft*P*dFo_dW -Fo*P*dFt_dW +Fo*Ft*dP_dW)/Ft**2
    dPp_dW  = (Fp*P*dFp_dW -Fp*P*dFt_dW +Fp*Ft*dP_dW)/Ft**2
    dPa_dW  = (Fa*P*dFa_dW -Fa*P*dFt_dW +Fa*Ft*dP_dW)/Ft**2
    dPc_dW  = (Fc*P*dFc_dW -Fc*P*dFc_dW +Fc*Ft*dP_dW)/Ft**2
    
    df = np.array([dFet_dW, dFac_dW, dFo_dW, dFp_dW, dFa_dW, dFc_dW, dFt_dW, dPet_dW, dPac_dW, dPo_dW, dPp_dW, dPa_dW, dPc_dW, dP_dW])
    df = df / TIME_SCALE
    return df 

# Integration points
W_span = np.array([0, 8572]) #* TIME_SCALE
points = np.linspace(W_span[0], W_span[1], num = 101)

# Initial conditions
P_0 = 128       # psi
T   = 423       # Kelvin

Fet_0, Fac_0, Fo_0, Fp_0, Fa_0, Fc_0 = 11, 11, 1.9, 0, 0, 0
Ft_0  = Fet_0 + Fac_0 + Fo_0

Pp_0, Pa_0, Pc_0  = 0, 0, 0
Pet_0 = (Fet_0/Ft_0)*P_0
Pac_0 = (Fac_0/Ft_0)*P_0
Po_0  = (Fo_0/Ft_0)*P_0
P_0   = Pet_0 + Pac_0 + Po_0

y_0 = np.array([Fet_0, Fac_0, Fo_0, Fp_0, Fa_0, Fc_0, Ft_0, Pet_0, Pac_0, Po_0, Pp_0, Pa_0, Pc_0, P_0])

# Constants
phi = 0.5                                                                        # Void fraction
A_c = 0.0122718463                                                               # straight section area of the catalyst  [ ft ^2 ]
rho_c = 60                                                                       # dry catalyst density                   [ lb / ft ^3 ]    
g_c = 115826.4                                                                   # gravity conversion factor              [ lb * ft / (min ^2 *lbf) ]
D_p = 0.020833333                                                                # average particle diameter              [ ft ]
M_0 = (28.05 * Fet_0 + 60.052 * Fac_0 + 31.998 * Fo_0) / (Ft_0)                  # molar mass of the initial mixture      [ lb / lbmol]
rho_0 = (128 * M_0) / (10.73 + 731.07)                                           # Initial density                        [ lb / ft  ^3 ]

# Solution IVP
sol = solve_ivp(f, W_span, y_0, t_eval=points, method='DOP853')
W   = sol.t / TIME_SCALE
Fet = sol.y[0]
Fac = sol.y[1]
Fo  = sol.y[2]
Fp  = sol.y[3]
Fa  = sol.y[4]
Fc  = sol.y[5]
Ft  = sol.y[6]
Pet = sol.y[7]
Pac = sol.y[8]
Po  = sol.y[9]
Pp  = sol.y[10]
Pa  = sol.y[11]
Pc  = sol.y[12]
P   = sol.y[13]

variable_names = ['Fet', 'Fac', 'Fo', 'Fp', 'Fa', 'Fc', 'Ft', 'Pet', 'Pac', 'Po', 'Pp', 'Pa', 'Pc', 'P']
for v, n in zip(sol.y, variable_names):
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(sol.t / TIME_SCALE, v)
    plt.title(n)
    plt.grid()

print(sol.message)

